# How can I get the open new issues, confirmed new issues, false positive new issues?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

This is a screen where we configure our project, SonarQube shows new issues open, confirmed which is highlighted in yellow, I am using the SonarQube API in my application and want to dump the data to my DB. Accordingly I will create the report. But In Sonar Metrics document I do not find how could I get these value using API. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`api/issues/search` should get you all you need. Check out the documentation embedded in your SonarQube server (linked at the footer).

From the use-case you describe, parameters *sinceLeakPeriod* or *createdAfter* / *createdInLast* can help out with date filtering. Not to mention other filters like *resolved* and *componentKeys*. Exchaustive listing is in the WebAPI documentation.

Comment: But my exact issue is. Using below URL i am getting all data which I need But only issue is I am not getting all new issues related records

http://mis-sonarqube:9000/api/resources?resource=4191&metrics=violations,blocker_violations,violations,critical_violations,major_violations,minor_violations,info_violations

Is there any way to get new false positive issue, new reopened issue, new opened issues, new confirmed issues for all projects which I configured in sonarqube at a time.

Comment: _api/resources_ is deprecated, and in fact it wouldn't even let you filter resolution state (false-positive, reopened etc.). _api/issues/search_ is the best way forward, as explained.